# JMSSecurityException: Not allowed to unsubscribe configured durable

Tags: jms, tibco-ems

I'm trying to close durable subscription so messages are not stored on server anymore.
I disconnect all listeners and do

```
ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory)context.lookup(tcfurl);

Connection connection = cf.createConnection(user, password);

connection.setClientID(clientId);

connection.start();

Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

TopicSubscriber subscriber = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, subName);

subscriber.close();

session.unsubscribe(subName);
```

Here I got exception "Not allowed to unsubscribe configured durable". I had an idea that it could be if some durable consumet is running, but I checked that they are not connected. 
Could you please advice on it?
Thanks.

Comment: The JMS specification defines exception types (e.g. `javax.jms.JMSException`), but it doesn't define particular error messages like the one you're seeing here (i.e. "Not allowed to unsubscribe configured durable"). Error messages like that come from the implementation itself. I Googled "Not allowed to unsubscribe configured durable" and there were no results. Tibco (someone familiar with it) will need to explain what that message means. As far as the code goes, everything looks fine.

Comment: I've updated question, it is JMSSecurityException

Comment: That narrows it down _a bit_. Per the JMS specification a `JMSSecurityException` "...must be thrown when a provider rejects a user name/password submitted by a client. It may also be thrown for any case where a security restriction prevents a method from completing." However, the exact problem is still particular to Tibco EMS.

Comment: Yes, I had an idea that maybe this operation is restricted by our Tibco admin team, so raised this question to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a limitation in our installation of tibco ems: it is not allowed to unsubscribe durable subscribers programmatically.